# Passing an HTML table to VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

The following controller code gets a result set and puts it in regular HTML tables. I need to pass this to a VF page.

1) Will it render like any webpage or do I need to wrap it in something?

2) How to actually pass it to the VF page. I need some code. I am not sure which apex tag to use and how to return the htmlCode to it. Despite I have been given other good examples in previous questions.

```
public class vfCtrlr_BOG_Committee_Report {

public void vfCtrlr_BOG_Committee_Report()  {   

List<BOG_Membership__c> bogQueryList = [Select BOG_Membership_Type_New__c, ORG__c, contact__r.Name 
FROM BOG_Membership__c 
WHERE BOG_Membership_Status__c = 'Active' 
AND BOG_Membership_Type_New__c <> '' 
ORDER BY BOG_Membership_Type_New__c , ORG__c, contact__r.Name ];

Set <String> memTypes = New Set <String>();
Set <String> orgs = New Set <String>();    

        for(BOG_Membership__c record :bogQueryList)
        {
            memTypes.add((String) record.get('BOG_Membership_Type_New__c'));
            orgs.add((String) record.get('ORG__c'));
        }
String htmlCode ='';

        for(String mem : memTypes)
        {
            htmlCode = htmlCode + '<Table><TH>The Committe Report</TH>';
            htmlCode = htmlCode + '<TR><TD>'+mem+'</TD></TR>';
            for(String org : orgs)
            {

                htmlCode = htmlCode + '<TR><TD>'+org+'</TD></TR>';

                for(BOG_Membership__c record :bogQueryList)
                {
                    if((String) record.get('ORG__c') == org && (String) record.get('BOG_Membership_Type_New__c') == mem)
                    {
                        htmlCode = htmlCode + '<TR><TD>'+(String) record.get('contact__r.Name')+'</TD></TR>';

                    } 
                }   
            }
            htmlCode = htmlCode + '</Table>';
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: I.e. This doesn't work <apex:page controller="vfCtrlr_BOG_Committee_Report">
<apex:outputText value="{!htmlCode}" />
</apex:page>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use `apex:outputtext` with `escape = false`

First make you `htmlCode` string to get set to access this in VF page.

And in VF page

```
<apex:outputText value="{!htmlCode }" escape="false" />
```

**[Escape](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm)**

> A Boolean value that specifies whether sensitive HTML and XML
>   characters should be escaped in the HTML output generated by this
>   component. If you do not specify escape="false", the character escape
>   sequence displays as written. Be aware that setting this value to
>   "false" may be a security risk because it allows arbitrary content,
>   including JavaScript, that could be used in a malicious manner.

---

### Updates

If you want to access the string in VF page.

```
public class yourclassName
{
   public String htmlCode {get;set;}
   public yourclassName()
  {
    //rest code here
  }
}
```

after that you can access `htmlCode` in VF page

```
<apex:outputText value="{!htmlCode }" escape="false" />
```

**[Check this Documentation Apex Properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm)**

Comment: I get an Uknown Property htmlCode error. Why doesn't it see my variable?

Comment: @ApexN-u-b like I said in my ans `htmlCode ` should be get set property in controller.

Comment: @ApexN-u-b Because first you have to declare and then initialize the variable `htmlCode` in controller: `public String htmlCode { get; set; }`

Comment: Gulp. What is the syntax to make it get set?

Comment: @ApexN-u-b if you don't use get set you can't access the variable in VF page..

Comment: I pasted public String htmlCode { get; set; } in the code. In the function I got same error as above or if I put it outside the method I get expecting semi-colon. Where exactly do I paste it?

Comment: @ApexN-u-b Can you check my updates in my ans. Also can you add your updated code what you have tried so far in your question ? it will be helpful to review your code

Comment: how do you update code, use edit?

Comment: I had to go. Update. The table is showing nicely thanks to you but I can't get the contact__r.Name value which I need. What do I need to do?      if((String) record.get('ORG__c') == org && (String) record.get('BOG_Membership_Type_New__c') == mem) 
     { 
      // htmlCode = htmlCode + '<TR><TD>'+(String) record.get('contact__r.Name')+'</TD></TR>'; 

     } 
    }